# Detect collision between Actors

Tags: libgdx, collision, actor

I'm trying to implement a collision detector between my `Player` (Actor) and my `Obstacle` (Actor too), and I wonder what's the best way to perform a `collision detection` between them. I see some users saying that they create a `Rectangle object` in the class and update its bounds every frame, but I don't know if this is the best way to perform this (I'm also trying to make this, but my collision detector method triggers before my Player touches the Obstacle).

This is what I'm trying to check:

```
public boolean touchedWall() {
    // Loop for the obstacles
    for (Obstacle obstacle : this.world.getObstacles()) {
        // Check if player collided with the wall
        if (this.bounds.overlaps(obstacle.getBounds())) {
            Gdx.app.log(Configuration.TAG, "collided with " + obstacle.getName());              
            return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

And this is where the method triggers (it should trigger when the Player bounds hit the wall):

[image: Position where the method triggers]

Comment: What is the type of "bounds" referenced in "this.bounds.overlaps(obstacle.getBounds())"?

Comment: In both Actors I did this: `private Rectangle bounds`. Is that you wanted to know?  I don't know why this happens because I did the difference between the X position of the Rectangle and the X position of the actor bounds and the result was 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out! Instead of using `this.bounds.set(x, y, width, height)`, I was using `this.bounds.set(x, y, height, width)` like this:

```
this.bounds.set(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getHeight(), this.getWidth());
```

Sorry for my mistake.